# MPAndroidChart - First and last bars not rendering correctly

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

1. In the bar chart I am creating the first and last rows are consistently being cut in half (even if I add additional bars). This also causes the values above the bars to be out of place. I am inflating this within a fragment.
2. The axis are also only increasing by 0.9 instead of 1. To fix this do I need to implement the AxisValueFormatter interface?

Image:

[image]

Code:
.java

```
chart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);

// Chart settings
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
chart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(true);
chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
chart.setDescription("");

// Settings for X-Axis
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setEnabled(true);
xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

// Settings for Y-Axis
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();

leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);

BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();

BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(2f, 1));
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(3f, 2));
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(4f, 3));
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(5f, 4));
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(6f, 5));

Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");

Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

BARDATA = new BarData(Bardataset);

chart.setData(BARDATA);
chart.invalidate(); // refresh

chart.animateY(1500);

return view;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. In order to properly show your bars you need to fit the bars, like this (don't ask me why it's not enabled by default):

   ```
   chart.setFitBars(true)
   ```

   You can find more information in the `BarChart` javadocs:

   > [`setFitBars(boolean enabled)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/BarChart.html#setFitBars-boolean-): Adds half of the bar width to each side of the x-axis range in order to allow the bars of the barchart to be fully displayed.

   If you have a `CombinedChart` you could use [`setSpaceMin()`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.html#setSpaceMin-float-) and [`setSpaceMax()`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.html#setSpaceMax-float-) to add additional spacing on both ends of the axis:

   ```
   XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
   xAxis.setSpaceMin(barData.getBarWidth() / 2f);
   xAxis.setSpaceMax(barData.getBarWidth() / 2f);
   ```
2. It is currently impossible to infuence the value positions rendered on the axis. Creating a `ValueFormatter` only changes the displayed text, not the actual position of the label.

Comment: It's a sad world we live when you have to manually set something that should have been already set by default.

Comment: How can we achieve this with a CombinedChart?

Comment: @Nfear Have you got any solution for Combined charts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064664/mpandroidchart-combinedchart-first-and-last-bars-arent-visible-completely

Comment: @Nfear @Prabs I've updated the answer with a solution that should work with `CombinedChart`s.

Comment: I'm not going to talk about how much time I wasted trying to hack this using min and max values.

Comment: @TR4Android could you help me with CustomCombinedChartRenderer? I've created a custom class which rotates the label, it is working fine with bar and line, but in combined, labels aren't rotated

Answer (score 3):

Please use `setAxisMinimum` and `setAxisMaximum`, it will work perfectly!

After your `BarData` is instantiated, you just need

```
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(-data.getBarWidth() / 2);
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(count-data.getBarWidth() / 2);`
```

There is no need for `setFitBars`, and the count is `BARENTRY` size.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is with the first bar only, you can use negative values for the axis minimum:

```
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(-0.5f);
```

Like in the answer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064664/mpandroidchart-combinedchart-first-and-last-bars-arent-visible-completely):

Answer (score 1):

i just fixed it,settings the x range min, using

```
  barChart.setFitBars(true);
  barChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(barEntries.size());
```