# MPAndroidChart: BubbleChart first and last bubble rendered half shown

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Similar to [MPAndroidChart - First and last bars not rendering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838362/mpandroidchart-first-and-last-bars-not-rendering-correctly), the first and last bubble in my chart isn't rendered fully, and is sliced in half as seen in the image.

[image]

The following is the current implementation for the BubbleChart.

```
private void initializeBubbleChart() {
        mChart = (BubbleChart) findViewById(R.id.bubblechart);

        mChart .setDescription("");

        mChart .setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        mChart .setDrawGridBackground(false);

        mChart .setTouchEnabled(true);
        mChart .setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart .setScaleEnabled(true);

        AxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart);

        XAxis xAxis = mChart .getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setTypeface(typeFace);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

        AxisValueFormatter yAxis = new YAxisValueFormatter("duration");

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart .getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setTypeface(typeFace);
        leftAxis.setSpaceTop(30f);
        leftAxis.setSpaceBottom(30f);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(yAxis);
        leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart .getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setTypeface(typeFace);
        rightAxis.setSpaceTop(30f);
        rightAxis.setSpaceBottom(30f);
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setValueFormatter(yAxis);
        rightAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);

        populateData();
    }
```

@Philipp Jahoda

Comment: Did you try the answer  `chart.setFitBars(true)` from the linked post?  What happened?

Comment: @0X0nosugar that method can only be used for charts that draw bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setAxisMinValue()` and `setAxisMaxValue()` to customize the axis range:

```
xAxis.setAxisMinValue(valueBelowActualMinimum);
xAxis.setAxisMaxValue(valueAboveActualMaximum);
```

and modify the `DayAxisValueFormatter` to show or suppress labels for the edge values.

Comment: Thanks, that somehow solves the issue. Wish there were a similar method like `setFitBar()` for BubbleChart.

Comment: @Kai - yes, you are right. It sure would be convenient.