# MPAndroidChart - CombinedChart - First and last bars aren't visible completely

Tags: mpandroidchart

In `CombinedChart` by adding `chart.setFitBars(true)` will make the first and last bars visible.

I need to do the same for combining LineChart with BarChart.
Now, first and last bars aren't visible completely.

[image]

I've tried

```
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(data.getXMax() + 1f);
```

to extend `X-Axis` towards right side so that the last bar will get enough space. This did the trick.

But what should I do for left side bar?
`setAxisMinimum` doesn't help.

**After adding `setAxisMaximum` :**

[image]

**EDIT**

I've referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838362/mpandroidchart-first-and-last-bars-not-rendering-correctly)  but it gives the solution for only `BarChart`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPAndroidChart - First and last bars not rendering correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838362/mpandroidchart-first-and-last-bars-not-rendering-correctly)

Comment: @TR4Android Nope. The solution provided there isn't applicable for CombinedChart

Comment: I've added a solution for `CombinedChart`s using `setSpaceMin()` and `setSpaceMax()` on the `XAxis` of the chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it.

`xAxis.setAxisMinimum(-0.5f);`

[image]

I guess, Edited X-Axis label will make it look good.

For editing labels in `MPAndroidchart` refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499401/2820534)

Comment: This might be better as an additional answer on the question @TR4Android mentioned as duplicate rather than a separate Q&A here. Your answer applies to `BarChart` as well as `CombinedChart`.