# Android MPChart xAxis offset

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm building a simple bar graph, with android MPChart.

The problem I'm having is that the values are being offset about half of the bar width to the left:

[image: bar_graph]

I have set:
`barChart.setExtraOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 16f)`

`barChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0f`

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

As it is only for the first bar, try negative value:

```
barChart.xAxis.setAxisMinimum(-0.5f);
```

For more details: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064664/mpandroidchart-combinedchart-first-and-last-bars-arent-visible-completely)

Comment: this will change the xaxis label value, instead of moving it